# java spring apllication integration with matlab playground

Tags: java, matlab, octave, matlab-java

I have an java-spring-angular application where i would like to introduce matlab plaground. I am using GNU octave(https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index) for executing matlab code. Is there a working small example for the integration. eg:javaoctave

Answer (score 0):

Octave has a java interface.

You will find documentation with examples in the relevant section of the octave manual: https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Java-Interface.html#Java-Interface